# Intalled Dspace on Debian, 404 error stays after copying files to tomcat webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, dspace

This is my first time installing Dspace,
I followed the tutorial from the duraspace site.

wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace

- Mvn package was a succes.
- Building the package with ant was a succes.
- Initializing the database was successful

I also added the needed xml files to /etc/tomcat7/localhost/

I then started my tomcat service but 127.0.0.1:8080/xmlui gives me a 404.
The original tomcat pages(docs,...) do work.

I've already looked at the

/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out for seeing what goes wrong and found no errors. So I'm out of inspiration.

I have never worked with Dspace or Tomcat before.
It could be that I looked over something small.

Some help would be welcome. Thank you very much

If it can help these are the files inside my Catalina/localhost

[Files inside Catalina/localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVT3v.png)

Inside the not standard xml files the code is (as example xmlui.xml):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Context
docBase="/dspace/webapps/xmlui"
reloadable="true"
cachingAllowed="false"/>
```

The files inside the /dspace/webapps/xmlui as ls:

```
aspects             exception2html.xslt  META-INF      static  WEB-INF
exception2dri.xslt  i18n                 sitemap.xmap  themes
```

About rights: It should not be a problem. For now I just dit a chmod -R 777 on the /dspace folder.

A remembrance that all services run except of my rest, xmlui and jspui.

the log of my tomcat starting up in /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out:

https://gist.github.com/RoelKint/06795ccc0fc8c56367554e4c860c8ded

Comment: When I try to start the xmlui webapp from the tomcat _Application manager_ it just says:     **FAIL - Application at context path /xmlui could not be started**

Comment: Same for the jspui **FAIL - Application at context path /jspui could not be started**

Comment: It would be useful if you could show us the content of the files you've added to /etc/tomcat7/localhost. Also, is there anything in the tomcat log file (probably `/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out` or similar)?

Comment: As you asked, I added an image of me doing an ls inside localhost and the stack of my tomcat.

Comment: You need to tell us which of the files has the content you copied. Is that the `xmlui.xml` one, and do the others have the docBase adjusted appropriately? Is your XMLUI actually installed in `/dspace/webapps/xmlui` -- that is, does that directory exist and contain files? Is that directory readable by the user running tomcat?

Comment: I added the information you asked for. I noticed the logs of the tomcat already got deleted. i'm looking for a site to copy my log in to so it stays readable.

Comment: Added /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out logs with the use of gist

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Is there anything in the DSpace log file? I note your gist says `SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file` but I don't know where those container log files would be.

Comment: I will start over from a clean Tomcat install.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was I copied all the Solr cores to `/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets` instead of to `/var/solr/data`, as it should on a Debian (11 in my case). From [step 13 on the documentation](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-BackendInstallation):

```
# [solr] is the location where Solr is installed.
# NOTE: On Debian systems the configsets may be under /var/solr/data/configsets
cp -R [dspace]/solr/* [solr]/server/solr/configsets
```

Seems that [in other cases](https://dspacegeek.blogspot.com/2017/10/http-status-404.html) is a permissions issue.